# How to delete the other hexagons?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to draw a hexagon surrounded by hexagons congruent to the original, with a total of 7 hexagons. I can do, but I can't delete the rest.

```
\documentclass[border=2mm, tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=7.5mm,y=4.34mm]
  \tikzset{box/.style={regular polygon, regular polygon sides=6,     
        minimum size=10mm,       
      inner sep=0mm,outer sep=0mm, rotate=0, draw }  }
\foreach \i in {0,...,1} 
    \foreach \j in {0,...,2} {\node[box] at (2*\i,2*\j) {};           
        \node[box] at (2*\i+1,2*\j+1) {}; }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Does this work for you?

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=2mm, tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
   x=7.5mm,y=4.34mm,
   box/.style={
      regular polygon,
      regular polygon sides=6,     
      minimum size=10mm,       
      inner sep=0mm, outer sep=0mm,
      draw}
 ]
\node [box] (innerbox) {};
\foreach [evaluate=\x as \y using {int(ifthenelse(\x+2>6,\x-4,\x+2))}] \x in {1,...,6}
  \node [box,anchor=corner \y] at (innerbox.corner \x) {\pgfmathparse{int(mod(\x,2))}\pgfmathresult};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Torbjorn T. - Perfect! Works great!

Comment: Torbjorn T. In the hexagons of the ring, can I number them alternately 0 and 1?

Comment: @benedito Like that (see edited answer)?

Comment: Torbjorn T. Show!

Comment: Torbjorn T. - What is the command that makes switch 0 and 1?

Comment: Torbjorn T. - I am interested in naming them in a special way

Comment: @benedito I added just one thing in the second iteration of the answer (`\pgfmathparse{int(mod(\x,2))}\pgfmathresult`), that's what switches between 0 and 1. Do you need an explanation of that? As for your second comment, you really need to be more specific, how am I possibly supposed to understand what you want. (Also, please don't come up with ever new additional requests, it's actually a bit annoying, couldn't you have written everything in the question in the first place?)

Comment: Torbjorn T. -OK! It occurred to me another problem. But, not to disregard the norm here, I will make another question more specific. Thanks.